# How to speed up of Displaying Messages (success,Error,Notice) in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, messages

Currently in Magento2 site Success,Error or Notice Message taking too much time to display.

How to speed up?

Comment: you are which mode testing ?

Comment: Production mode @RakeshDonga